# Why can't I activate my virtual environment?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, virtualenv

I created a Python virtual environment in `D:\Envs\.venv1`.

I can activate it by specifying a relative path, for example:

```
PS D:\> .\Envs\.venv1\Scripts\activate
(.venv1) PS D:\>
```

But, when I try to specify an absolute path, it does not work:

```
PS D:\> \Envs\.venv1\Scripts\activate
PS D:\>
```

Here, after I click "Enter", I see a flashing window, which closes immediately, and then I get the prompt back, and as you see, I am not in my virtual environment.

Is there a way to activate my virtual environment through an absolute path?

Comment: I don't know why the relative version worked, but with Powershell, you should use `activate.ps1`.

Comment: Maybe powershell has special handling for commands that start with a backslash?  Try putting the drive letter in front.  `D:\Envs\.venv1\Scripts\activate`

Comment: When you use a relative path without an extension, PowerShell will actually run `activate.ps1`. But with an absolute path, I assume it tries to run `activate`, which is a Bash script, so it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typed

```
\Envs\.venv1\Scripts\activate
```

Instead, use

```
\Envs\.venv1\Scripts\activate.ps1
```